# Complex Integral over a Square Path

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I'm struggling to set up this integral as I just started learning complex analysis.

Let C be the perimeter of the square with vertices at the points z = 0, z = 1, z = 1 +i and z = i.

$$\int_C \bar{z}^2dz$$

What would my 4 path integrals be? I'm super confused. Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path $z = t$ will form a path from $0$ to $1$

$z = 1 + it$ will be a path from $1$ to $1+i$

$\bar z = (x - iy)\\
\bar z^2 = x^2 - y^2 - 2xy i$

$\int_0^1 t^2  \ dt + \int_0^1 1 - t^2 - 2t \ dt + \cdots$

Work out the last two paths and set up two more integrals.

Comment: Okay so from my understanding would the next two paths be $\int_0^1 (-it)^2dt + \int_0^1 t^2 dt$?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do the next path is $z = t+ i$ with t traveling from 1 to 0 and the integral will be $\int_1^0 t^2 - 1 - 2ti \ dt = \int_0^1 -t^2 + 1 + 2ti \ dt$ and the final path $z = it$ again traveling in the negative direction.  $\int_1^0 -t^2  \ dt = \int_0^1 t^2 \ dt$

Comment: Are you just using the formula $z(t) = z_1 + t( z_2 - z_1)$?